# Subtracting weeks and months from a date - Is my math correct?

Tags: php, date, math

I have an input field where the user can set an interval of weeks (only integers). Those weeks are subtracted from an original date in a database. I am using PHP to subtract the weeks and/or months with the following methods:

```
$date_call_in = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$months months", strtotime($date_call_in)));

$date_call_in = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-$weeks weeks", strtotime($date_call_in)));
```

The problem came if the user enters more than 3 weeks (e.g 4 weeks) as the PHP date function wont calculate and decrement a month, but a maximum of 3 weeks. So if the user entered 4 weeks it would decrement only 3 weeks because it could not understand and shift the month.

Therefore I had to make a smaller calculation to translate the remainding weeks from a month if the input was higher than 3 weeks.

This is my result and it seems to work like a charm. I would be grateful tho if anyone could spot something I have overseen since I dont consider myself a great mathematican.

Here is my function, created in Javascript for the simplicity:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hq5cp6j3/1/)

And the code in the fiddle is:

```
var weeks = 7; //feel free to change this for testing

if (weeks < 4){
  alert ("weeks: " + weeks);
}else{
  var months = Math.floor(weeks/4);
  weeks = weeks % 4;
  alert("months: " + months + ", weeks: " + weeks);
}
```

Do you agree with the solution or did I miss something? Thanks for taking your time to read this.

**EDIT:**
Here is a link to the whole method: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/7b4hvA5P)

Comment: So what's the problem with [subtracting more than 3 weeks](http://3v4l.org/mC2b9)?

Comment: PHP function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) gladly subtracts as many weeks you need, be it 3 or 4 or 444. What is the problem you intend to solve?

Comment: The problem is that the PHP's date function cant translate that into months. It would just cap the weeks at a maximum of 3. I have to manually set the weeks (and months if any) for the date function to understand it correctly. I tried with 4+ weeks and it would only decrement the date within the months (hence: 3 weeks if the month was on the 30th). I also tried to divide the weeks by 4 and use months instead, but of course, the subtracted value would increment instead of decrementing. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Your workaround has a big flow: it converts 52 weeks to "13 months, 0 weeks" but any calendar will tell you a bit different: 52 weeks is 1 year (minus 1 day) and the year currently has 12 months.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much for sharing this Axiac. Guess it is not the way to go around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem came if the user enters more than 3 weeks (e.g 4 weeks) as the PHP date function wont calculate and decrement a month, but a maximum of 3 weeks.

I tested what you've said and got the right answer as I expected. Here is my code.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-5 weeks", strtotime('2015-07-19')));
echo $date;
```

And here is what I got:
`2015-06-14`

See, it work perfectly.  You can dump the value before and after the process see if it's your code or some other things is wrong.

Hope you can fix it.

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I tried it again. I now put a pastebin of the code in my question. Line 4 is the weeks from the DB. Line 19 is the date alteration.

When the original date is 30-09-2015 and the weeks to subtract are 4, the result is 02-09-2015. I find that odd?

Edit: When the original date is 30-09-2015 and the weeks to subtract are 5, the date is 26-08-2015. Hmm :-)

Comment: Your date format is like 'Y-m-d' while your data from the database is like 'd-m-Y', change either of them may work.

Comment: Oh my god... The whole thing was correct from the start. 4 weeks = 28 days, not 30... So the result was not odd at all.. Gosh.. Im gonna have a large coffee now and a napkin for my tears to come. Thanks for pointing it out for me. Such a great help!